# Logo image displaying at incorrect aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

According to Lighthouse, the main logo at the top of our page [(nrsmart.com)](https://nrsmart.com) is being displayed at the wrong aspect ratio. File name: `nrsmart-logo-longtext.png`. I've tried a bunch of things - including removing the image from the container (`.thehomepage`). Why is this happening? My CSS code looks correct to me... The other large image on the home page (`nrs-nrsmart-national-remarketing-service.jpg`) resizes fine with no aspect ratio change... So why would the logo have trouble?

Here is the Lighthouse report:
Displays images with incorrect aspect ratio
Image display dimensions should match natural aspect ratio.

Aspect Ratio (Displayed): 412 x 36 (11.44)
Aspect Ratio (Actual): 800 x 69 (11.59)

```
.responsivelogo {
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

It's in a container (`.thehomepage`):

```
.thehomepage {
  z-index:9999990;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Any ideas? This is driving the perfectionst inside me insane!

Comment: What dimensions were you expecting? There’s no way to perfectly scale with the scale multiplier between those two resolutions. The scaling is correct to within less than one pixel. Also, the other image you reference also has non-perfect scaling, it just depends on the browser size.

Comment: I posted about this a while back at Lighthouse - someone there suggested their analysis in the Lighthouse software is too strict. Thanks for helping clarify for me... I didn't realize my other image had non-perfect scaling. Lighthouse didn't report that one...

Comment: Shows correct to me. I think your report is testing on mobile devices and your logo is responsive so it adapts it's width, but the Lighthouse thinks it should be 800*69 since you specified it in the element. 

Solutions I can think of:
1) Instead of Height, Width set Max-Width
2) Maybe there is an option in the Lighthouse to ignore such issues

Answer (score 0):

As someone at Lighthouse suggested (that their analysis may have been too strict), they may have made a change to the way Lighthouse does their analysis.  I just scanned our site again, and the image aspect ratio error I was getting before is gone.  It no longer appears when I analyze our site, so the issue appears to be resolved.